# Rx in MVC architecture

Tags: java, model-view-controller, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

While learning RX i have come across the question on how to design the architecture when UI is involved.

The use case: click button -> perform business actions (download & parse webpage) -> update view

I see two straightforward approaches:

1. build Observable containing the UI events, then transform it using map(), finally subscribe the view to it.
2. build Observable containing the UI events, build the second Observable containing the responses, link the two observables 
   (zipWith),  finally subscribe the view to it.

In the 1st approach, my business logic is more or less implemented in some functions `Function<INPUT, OUTPUT>`. In my use case here i download the web page, then parse it. Then my business/service method would look like:

```
Observable<Event> getEventsFromWeb(Observable<Click> clicks) {
    return clicks.map(downloadWebPage()).map(parseWebPage(parser)); }
```

In the 2nd approach, my business/service method gets directly result i need.

```
Observable<Event> getEventsFromWeb() {
    return Observble.create( /*download web page*/).map(parseWebPage(parser)); }
```

Then i have to link the the getEventsFromWeb() Observable to the UI clicks observable, so that the action is actually triggered by UI.

```
clicks.zipWith(getEventsFromWeb(), (click, Events) -> Events))
```

Now i'm not sure which of these two (or other) is better to use with RX.
I kind of like the first one because is a straightforward transformation of the stream with map(), but the service needs the extra parameter (extra coupling).

The second approach does not have the extra coupling (method parameter), so it is more flexible, it is more clear what happens (the extra parameter seems weird to have), i think it can be tested better, but im not sure if zipWith() is the way to link it to the UI events.

What do you think? Are there any better approaches to link the model to the UI events?

Comment: instead of  `clicks.zipWith(getEventsFromWeb(), (click, Events) -> Events))`  i can do  `clicks.flatMap((e)->getEventsFromWeb())` which looks way better

Answer (score 0):

MVVM might be a better way, 
example: https://medium.com/@manuelvicnt/rxjava-android-mvvm-app-structure-with-retrofit-a5605fa32c00#.4vu081tua